# Is there a way to get access properties from a multiple nested looping groovy test step to utilize the values in other test steps in readyapi

Tags: loops, groovy, ready-api

I have a project which consists of a rest step and utilizing these values to sql and another groovy step that takes values from the data source of the rest request.

Now for certain dynamic values I need to utilize another rest request and have to write a groovy script to get properties to the existing project.

Problem : I have a nested json and I need to grab 3 to 4 values from multiple objects and utilize them in the existing script

Comment: Sounds like a job for `JsonSlurper`. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

A good way to reuse values generated or reuse values in general in ReadyAPI is to leverage the "Property Transfer Test Step" This test-step will allow you to store values that you may come to use later.

Take a look for more information on property-transfer here
https://support.smartbear.com/readyapi/docs/functional/steps/property-transfer.html